# In alpine flow got error var is not defined

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

in my Laravel 8 /  tailwindcss 2 / Alpinejs 2.8 app
on the page I load listing of data with axios and fill my template in alkpine template circle :

```
<div class="editor_form_wrapper w-10/12" x-data="adminAdEditorComponent()">
   ...
            <div x-show="activeTab === 2" class="p-2">
                Tab #2 : Categories
                <div id="div_ad_categories">
                    <table x-show="adCategories.length">
                        <tbody>

                        <template x-for="nextCategory in adCategories" :key="nextCategory.id">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="editor_listing_cell" x-text="nextCategory.id">



function adminAdEditorComponent() {
    console.log('adminAdEditorComponent::')

    return {
        adCategories: [],
        showDatepicker: false,
        ...
        loadAdCategories: function () {
            window.axios.get('/admin/ads/{{ $ad->id }}/ad_categories', {}).then((response) => {
                console.log('response.data::')
                console.log(response.data)
                adCategories = response.data.categories
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            })
```

And in the console I gor warning :

```
Alpine Error: "ReferenceError: adCategories is not defined"
Expression: "adCategories"
Element: <template x-for=​"nextCategory in adCategories" :key=​"nextCategory.id">​…​</template>​
```

But after this warning flow is continued and my listing is filled with data...
I tried to change condition, like

```
  <table x-show="typeof adCategories != 'undefined' &&  adCategories.length">
      <tbody>
```

but it did not help and I got warning anyway... How to fix these warnings...

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
it does not work .
I make :

```
loadAdCategories: function () {
    window.axios.get('/admin/ads/{{ $ad->id }}/ad_categories', {}).then((response) => {
        console.log('loadAdCategories response::')
        console.log(response)
        console.log('response.data::')
        console.log(response.data)
        console.log('this::')
        console.log(this)
        this.adCategories = response.data.categories
    }
}
```

and in browser : https://prnt.sc/104pqie

and what I see in browser :
2) I tried to define self:

```
function adminAdEditorComponent() {
    console.log('adminAdEditorComponent::')

    return {
        adCategories: [],
        ...
        loadAdCategories: function () {
            var self = this
            window.axios.get('/admin/ads/{{ $ad->id }}/ad_categories', {}).then((response) => {
                console.log('loadAdCategories response::')
                console.log(response)
                console.log('response.data::')
                console.log(response.data)
                self.adCategories = response.data.categories
```

and a lot of messages :

```
alpine.min.js:7 Alpine Error: "ReferenceError: adCategories is not defined"
```

in the broswer : https://prnt.sc/104pm4a

in both cases listing of categories is not filled.
As I wrote in my case with:

```
   adCategories = response.data.categories
```

listing of categories is filled ok. Looks like at line :

Thanks!

Comment: You need to do `this.adCategories = response.data.categories` I think

Comment: pls look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced the same problem, the only difference was that I received data on button click. Thanks to [Hugo for his tweet about async/await in alpine](https://twitter.com/hugo__df/status/1294333610569367552?s=20), it helped to make this work. Adopting this to your code, you should have (assuming your Alpine version is >= 2.6.0):

**Alpine js**

```
function adminAdEditorComponent() {
  return {
    adCategories: [],
    loadAdCategories: function() {
      window.axios.get('/admin/ads/{{ $ad->id }}/ad_categories', {})
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response)
          this.adCategories = response.data.categories
        })
    }
  }
}
```

**Blade**

```
<div class="editor_form_wrapper w-10/12" x-data="adminAdEditorComponent()" x-init="await loadAdCategories()">
  ...
  <div id="div_ad_categories">
    <table x-show="adCategories.length">
      <tbody>
        <template x-for="nextCategory in adCategories" :key="nextCategory.id">
        <tr>
          <td class="editor_listing_cell" x-text="nextCategory.id"></td>
        </tr>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```